# Ansible task to start mongod service hangs forever

Tags: mongodb, ansible

This task fails after 60 seconds, removing the async and poll just causes it for  hang forever. If it the playbook is run again the task completes successfully. This is being run on CentOS 7

```
- name: Start mongod service
  async: 60
  poll: 10
  service:
    enabled: yes
    name: mongod
    state: running
```

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "async task did not complete
>   within the requested time"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a systemd configuration for mongodb and then using the module `systemd` and not the `service` one.

**systemd example**

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Service
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/lib/mongod
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Task:

```
- name: Make sure a service is running
  systemd:
    state: started
    name: mongodb
```

systemd config source: [github](https://gist.github.com/jwilm/5842956)